# Unencrypted connection when sending mail using mailhog and golang

Tags: go, mailhog

These code works normally when using gmail (with [AllowLessSecureApp](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) turned on), but doesn't work with mailhog (`unencrypted connection` error), these the minimal code to reproduce:

```golang
package main
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/smtp"

    "github.com/jordan-wright/email"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestSendMail(t *testing.T) {
  m := struct{
    Host string
    Port int
    User string
    Pass string 
  }{
    Host: `local.test`, // resolved to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts
    Port: 1025,
    User: `test@local.test`,
    Pass: `test`,
  }
  e := email.NewEmail()
  e.From = `test@local.test`
  e.To = []string{`test@local.test`}
  e.Subject = `test mail`
  host, _ := os.Hostname()
  e.Text = []byte(`testing email from ` + host)
  err := e.SendWithStartTLS(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", m.Host, m.Port), smtp.PlainAuth("", m.User, m.Pass, m.Host), &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
  assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: test_mailhog
    env_file:
      - backend/.env # not used
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Or any workaround for this? eg. some TLS proxy on docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible that mailhog does not have proper TLS certs, and it listens without TLS on localhost, try using function https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jordan-wright/email#Email.Send to send email

```
err := e.Send(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", m.Host, m.Port),smtp.CRAMMD5Auth(m.User,m.Pass))
```

Comment: same error if using `.Send`, different error when using `.SendWithTLS`

Comment: only after changing `PlainAuth` to `CRAMMD5Auth` it works using `.Send`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like incoming TLS (i.e. work as TLS server) is not supported by mailhog - see the issue [STARTTLS support #296](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/issues/296).